# Refreshing the layout of a Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have an activity which uses ViewPager with 4 fragments. I am using FragmentPagerAdapter to populate the pages.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA()
            case 1:
                return new ProfileFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentD();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

One of these fragments shows the details of User (ProfileFragment in the above code) with following criteria:

- If the user isn't logged in, show login layout
- If the user is logged in, show profile layout

Hence, when user opens the app for the first time, the login layout will be shown and when user logs in, the fragment needs to be refreshed to show the profile layout.

The approach I was planning to take was that when user logs in, navigate him to FragmentA and destroy the existing ProfileFragment. The onCreateView method of ProfileFragment handles which layout to show based on login state.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int layout = userLoggedIn() ? R.layout.fragment_user_login : R.layout.fragment_user_profile;
        return inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
    }

    // Handler for login
    public void loginUser() {
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).loginUser();
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public void loginUser() {
        // 1. Set login details as needed
        ...
        // 2. Navigate to FragmentA
        ...
        // 3. Destroy ProfileFragment
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.destroyItem(container, 1, object); // How to get `object` here?
    }
}
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. The method destroyItem takes `Object object` returned from `instantiateItem`. How to get this value while destroying? Do I need to overwrite `instantiateItem` and maintain a `Map<Integer, Object>` from position to object?
2. Is there a better way to update the view of the fragment without destroying the fragment completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that before using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**, you can call **notifyDataSetChanged** the **getItemPosition** is called for each existing fragment if you call **super.getItemPosition** it returns **POSITION_UNCHANGED** when means the fragment has not changed if you return **POSITION_NONE** will cause the fragment at that position to be reloaded. you can use that in the **getItem** method to provide the profile fragment.

in this solution you just need to call **setLoggedIn**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
boolean isLoggedIn = false;
boolean userHasJustLoggedIn = false;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void setIsLoggedIn() {
    isLoggedIn = true;
    userHasJustLoggedIn = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentA()
        case 1:

            if (isLoggedIn) {
                return new ProfileFragment();
            } else {
                return new LoginFragment();
            }
        case 2:
            return new FragmentC();
        case 3:
            return new FragmentD();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
    if (fragment instanceof LoginFragment && userHasJustLoggedIn) {
        userHasJustLoggedIn = false;
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}
```

}

Comment: Awesome, this sounds great. We actually might not need the `userHasJustLoggedIn` flag. If user is logged in and the fragment is `LoginFragment`, we'll always need an update and hence return POSITION_NONE.

Comment: If you always need an update then remove the condition  userHasJustLoggedIn, if it's just a one time change then I suggest keeping this condition as it will prevent the fragment from reloading everytime.

Comment: I guess I accepted this too soon. I tried coding this, but it doesn't seem to work. `instantiateItem()` is called again as expected, but it never calls `getItem()` rather uses the same instance of `LoginView`. I looked into the source code of `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem()` and it calls getItem only if `FragmentManager` doesn't have a fragment, but in this case the fragment is never removed from the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter not FragmentPagerAdapter